# Openlayers - repeat labels along MultiLineString geometry

Tags: openlayers

Good morning,
I'm trying to configure a label that repeats every few meters/pixels/millimeters in a geometry type `MultiLineString`.
I would like a result like this configured with qgis:

[image]

Here is an example of the geojson:

```
var json_n440_68km_h423m_500 = {"type":"FeatureCollection","name":"n440_68km_h423m_500","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"Name":"Pagino Castello - Casa Peci - Col d'Orsola - Casa Campolino","Numero":"440","Tipologia":"Sentiero turistico"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[12.730385042615936,43.669223448744326],[12.730355957202569,43.669178166132973],[12.730326871831858,43.669132883514813 .....
```

My current style generates the label "Numero" only once at the start of the `MultiLineString`

```
var size = 0;
var placement = 'point';

var style_n440_68km_h423m_500 = function(feature, resolution){
    var context = {
        feature: feature,
        variables: {}
    };
    var value = ""
    var labelText = "";
    size = 0;
    var labelFont = "13.0px \'MS Shell Dlg 2\', sans-serif";
    var labelFill = "#000000";
    var bufferColor = "#ffffff";
    var bufferWidth = 1.0;
    var textAlign = "left";
    var offsetX = 8;
    var offsetY = 3;
    var placement = 'line';
    if (feature.get("Numero") !== null) {
        labelText = String(feature.get("Numero"));
    }
    var style = [ new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1.0)', lineDash: null, lineCap: 'round', lineJoin: 'round', width: 4}),
        text: createTextStyle(feature, resolution, labelText, labelFont,
                              labelFill, placement, bufferColor,
                              bufferWidth)
    }),new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'rgba(255,127,0,1.0)', lineDash: null, lineCap: 'round', lineJoin: 'round', width: 3}),
        text: createTextStyle(feature, resolution, labelText, labelFont,
                              labelFill, placement, bufferColor,
                              bufferWidth)
    })];

    return style;
};
```

**EDIT:**

With Mike's help I added this code which allows you to have the label repeated at the end of each piece of line. However the result in my case cannot be exposed because a thousand labels are represented because I am representing a very articulated mountain path.

```
    var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    geometry.getLineStrings().forEach(function(lineString) { 
    lineString.forEachSegment(function(start, end) {
      style.push(new ol.style.Style({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(end),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          feature: feature,
          resolution: resolution,
          text: labelText,
          font: labelFont,
          placement: placement,
          textAlign: textAlign,
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: labelFill
              }),
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: bufferColor, 
                width: bufferWidth
              }),
        }),
      }));
    }); 
  });
```

Result:
[image]

Do you have a solution for me?
Thanks

Comment: As long as you are using version 7.3.0 you can use the `repeat` option in the Text style https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Text-Text.html Example https://codesandbox.io/s/gpx-forked-zyh235?file=/main.js

Comment: I'm using openlayers 6.15.1

Comment: If you cannot upgrade you would need something like `geometry.getLineStrings().forEach(function(lineString) { lineString.forEachSegment(function(start, end) { /* add label */ }); });`

Comment: I've updated the question by adding the code you indicated, but it's not representable in my case. Do you have any ideas to repeat the labels fewer or according to a distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For equally spaced points before version 7.3.0 you should use the `getCoordinateAt()` method

Decide based on line length and resolution how many labels will fit, then get those points as a fraction of the line

```
  geometry.getLineStrings().forEach(function (line) {
    const length = line.getLength();
    const intervals = Math.ceil(length / (interval * resolution));
    for (let i = 1; i < intervals; ++i) {
      const point = line.getCoordinateAt(i / intervals);
      const style = labelStyle.clone();
      style.setGeometry(new Point(point));
      styles.push(style);
    }
  });
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/gpx-forked-b8e51i?file=/main.js

`for (let i = 1; i < intervals; ++i)` will not place labels at the start and end of the line, use for `(let i = 0; i <= intervals; ++i)` to include them.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Mike, whom I thank once again, the result is optimal.
Evaluate yourself against the image in the question.
[image]

I adapted the code slightly to my case,

```
var interval = 250;
var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
if (geometry.getType() === 'MultiLineString') {
  geometry.getLineStrings().forEach(function (line) {
    var length = line.getLength();
    var intervals = Math.ceil(length / (interval * resolution));
    for (let i = 1; i < intervals; ++i) {   
      var point = line.getCoordinateAt(i / intervals);
      var styletext = new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          text: labelText,
          font: labelFont,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: labelFill
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: bufferColor, 
            width: bufferWidth
          }),
        })
     });
      styletext.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(point));
      style.push(styletext);
    }
  });
}
return style;
};
```